# Redundant type checking for function?

Tags: javascript, typechecking

In the Polyfill section of the [`Array.prototype.forEach` js mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Polyfill), you can find the following check:

```
if (typeof callback !== 'function') {
    throw new TypeError(callback + ' is not a function');
}
```

In this specific case, why bother checking for function? During my tests, calling the function directly yields the exact same behavior

```
var callback;
callback();
// Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function

var callback = "";
callback();
// Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function

var callback = 2;
callback();
// Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function

var callback = [];
callback();
// Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function

var callback = {};
callback();
// Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function
```

Actually it's a little bit worse with this type of string concatenation, because we might see `"[object Object] is not a function"`:

```
function newCallback(val){
    if (typeof val !== 'function') {
        throw new TypeError(val+ ' is not a function');
    }
}
newCallback({});
//Uncaught TypeError: [object Object] is not a function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In this specific case, why bother checking for function?

If the array is empty, there won’t be an attempt to call the function, but it [should still fail](https://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.18).

```js
[].forEach('foo')
```

There’s also a difference for non-empty arrays when element access has side-effects:

```
let foo = {
    get [0]() {
        alert(1);
    }
};

Array.prototype.forEach.call(foo, …);
// alert shows up if the early type check is missing
```

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour of forEach is is defined that way [15.4.4.18 Array.prototype.forEach](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.18):

> 1. Let `O` be the result of calling `ToObject` passing the `this` value as the argument.
> 2. Let `lenValue` be the result of calling the `[[Get]]` internal method of `O` with the argument `"length"`.
> 3. Let `len` be `ToUint32(lenValue)`.
> 4. If `IsCallable(callbackfn)` is `false`, throw a `TypeError` exception.
> 5. If `thisArg` was supplied, let `T` be `thisArg`; else let `T` be `undefined`.
> 6. Let `k` be `0`.
> 7. Repeat, while `k` < `len` 
>      [...]

And because the polyfill is implemented according to the specification, the test if `callbackfn` is a function (**4.**) has to be done before the iteration starts (**7.**). And because of that the error will also be thrown even if `callbackfn` is not called (in the case when `len` is `0`).

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed that they don't explicitly call the `callback` like I did (`callback()`) but rather they do `callback.call()`, which no longer yields the same behavior and in this case makes sense to ensure the object is of type function.

```
// Call the Call internal method of callback with T as
// the this value and argument list containing kValue, k, and O.
callback.call(T, kValue, k, O);
```

Comment: That's one reason, but to be fully compatible to the specification, the error has to be thrown no matter if the array is empty or not. So the test is done explicitly before the iteration and not implicitly by the call.